# json.parse проверка на пустоту

Tags: javascript

скрипт выдает ошибку Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
показывает что ошибка в этой строке var arr = JSON.parse(resp)[0].content;

```js
var showLogic = new function() {
  var that = this;
  that.init = function() {
    var REQ = new XMLHttpRequest();
    REQ.open("POST", "/api/");
    REQ.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    REQ.send("action=purchases");
    REQ.onreadystatechange = function() {
      var resp = this.response;
      if (!!resp) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(resp)[0].content;
        var html = '<thead><tr><td id="select-all-inputs"><span>Все</span></td><td><span>QR-code</span></td><td class="sorted-column"><span>ФИО</span></td><td><span>Контакты</span></td><td><span>ID</span></td><td><span>Дата покупки</span></td><td><span>Бонусов <b>F</b></span></td><td><span>Бонусные покупки</span></td></tr></thead><tbody>';
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          var image = arr[i].qr,
            date = arr[i].purchase_date;
          var bonus_purchs_item = arr[i].bonus_purchs;
          var bonus_purchs = "",
            bonus_purchs_id = "";
          for (var bp = 0; bp < bonus_purchs_item.length; bp++) {
            bonus_purchs += bonus_purchs_item[bp] + '<br>';
          }
          var bonus_purchs_item_2 = arr[i].bonus_purchs_array;
          for (var bpa = 0; bpa < bonus_purchs_item_2.length; bpa++) {
            bonus_purchs_id += bonus_purchs_item_2[bpa].id + '=' + bonus_purchs_item_2[bpa].name + ';';

          }
          if (image.length == 0) {
            image = "images/no.svg"
          };
          html += '<tr><td><div class="checkbox-click-field"></div><input class="checkbox" id="f' + arr[i].id + '" type="checkbox" data-inner-array-of-id="' + bonus_purchs_id.slice(0, bonus_purchs_id.length - 1) + '"> <label for="f' + arr[i].id + '"></label></td><td><img src="' + image + '"></td><td><span class="table-user-name">' + arr[i].user.lname + '</span><br>' + arr[i].user.fname + ' ' + arr[i].user.ffname + '</td><td><b>' + arr[i].user.phone_num + '</b><br>' + arr[i].user.email + '</td><td>' + arr[i].extern_id + '</td><td>' + date.replace(" ", "<br>") + '</td><td><b>' + arr[i].awarded_bonuses + '</b> F</td><td>' + bonus_purchs + '</td></tr>';
        };
      };
      html += '</tbody>';
      document.getElementById('show-products').innerHTML = html;
      updateEventsLogic.init();
    };
    return false;
  };
  return that;
};
```

суть скрипта в том, что б показать список товаров
в другом разделе сайта, есть точно такой же скрипт, со списком уведомлений и он не выдает никаких ошибок
как видите в коде я сделал проверку this.response на пустоту, в другом разделе сайта эта проверка помогла, а тут не хочет

Comment: возможно пропущена закрывающая скобка, после закрывающий скобок фигурных зачем точка с запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что `onreadystatechane` вызывется не только по завершению запроса, но и на всем протяжении его выполнения. Т.е. если ответ не влез в один tcp пакет целиком, то callback вызовется с частичным ответом, в котором `this.readyState==3`. Вам необходимо перед проверкой ответа как такового - проверить, что `readyState==4`. 4 - статус завершившегося запроса.

```
var showLogic = new function() {
  var that = this;
  that.init = function() {
    var REQ = new XMLHttpRequest();
    REQ.open("POST", "/api/");
    REQ.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    REQ.send("action=purchases");
    REQ.onreadystatechange = function() {
      var resp = this.response;
      if (this.readyState != 4) return; // добавленый кусок
      if (!!resp) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(resp)[0].content;
        var html = '<thead><tr><td id="select-all-inputs"><span>Все</span></td><td><span>QR-code</span></td><td class="sorted-column"><span>ФИО</span></td><td><span>Контакты</span></td><td><span>ID</span></td><td><span>Дата покупки</span></td><td><span>Бонусов <b>F</b></span></td><td><span>Бонусные покупки</span></td></tr></thead><tbody>';
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          var image = arr[i].qr,
            date = arr[i].purchase_date;
          var bonus_purchs_item = arr[i].bonus_purchs;
          var bonus_purchs = "",
            bonus_purchs_id = "";
          for (var bp = 0; bp < bonus_purchs_item.length; bp++) {
            bonus_purchs += bonus_purchs_item[bp] + '<br>';
          }
          var bonus_purchs_item_2 = arr[i].bonus_purchs_array;
          for (var bpa = 0; bpa < bonus_purchs_item_2.length; bpa++) {
            bonus_purchs_id += bonus_purchs_item_2[bpa].id + '=' + bonus_purchs_item_2[bpa].name + ';';

          }
          if (image.length == 0) {
            image = "images/no.svg"
          };
          html += '<tr><td><div class="checkbox-click-field"></div><input class="checkbox" id="f' + arr[i].id + '" type="checkbox" data-inner-array-of-id="' + bonus_purchs_id.slice(0, bonus_purchs_id.length - 1) + '"> <label for="f' + arr[i].id + '"></label></td><td><img src="' + image + '"></td><td><span class="table-user-name">' + arr[i].user.lname + '</span><br>' + arr[i].user.fname + ' ' + arr[i].user.ffname + '</td><td><b>' + arr[i].user.phone_num + '</b><br>' + arr[i].user.email + '</td><td>' + arr[i].extern_id + '</td><td>' + date.replace(" ", "<br>") + '</td><td><b>' + arr[i].awarded_bonuses + '</b> F</td><td>' + bonus_purchs + '</td></tr>';
        };
      };
      html += '</tbody>';
      document.getElementById('show-products').innerHTML = html;
      updateEventsLogic.init();
    };
    return false;
  };
  return that;
};
```